# Logout from Flickr/Facebook - iOS

Tags: ios, social-networking

I login to these social networking websites not using safari, but using a `UIWebView` inside the app. But once logged in, I have not been able to log them out.
(Trying to use fb  SDK and ObjectiveFlickr, but their logout methods are also not helping.)

I tried removing cookies for 'login.yahoo.com' and 'facebook.com' but it didn't help. I want the login screen to come up, but instead of that, it directly asks for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

From `Facebook` :

```
//make access token nil here
//clear cache from webview
NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
for (cookie in [storage cookies])
{
    NSString* domainName = [cookie domain];
    NSRange domainRange = [domainName rangeOfString:@"facebook"];
    if(domainRange.length > 0)
    {
        [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
    }
}
```

From `Flickr` :

```
//make access token nil here
//clear cache from webview
NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
for (cookie in [storage cookies])
{
    NSString* domainName = [cookie domain];
    NSRange domainRange = [domainName rangeOfString:@"flickr"];
    if(domainRange.length > 0)
    {
        [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
    }
}
```